# Ultimate functor class which can read/write to l-values/r-values

Tags: c++

The aim is to provide a generic functor class which makes references able to bind to r-values. The trick is to trick the compiler into thinking that the r-value is an l-value by using a forwarding references.
Here is the code:

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename Functor>
struct Function {
    Functor func;
    template <typename ...Args>
    inline auto operator() (Args&&... args) {
        //I tried to provide a suitable error message if args were not valid parameters, but I can't get it to work...
        //static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<Functor, Args...>);
        return func(args...);
    }
};
```

Example use case:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <vector>
int main () {
    // Define function 
    auto push_back = Function([] (std::vector<int>& vec, int num) {vec.push_back(num); return vec;});
    auto x = std::vector{1 , 2 ,3 , 4};
    // Works on l-values
    push_back(x, 5);
    std::cout << x[4] << '\n'; // 5
    // Works on r-values
    auto y = push_back(std::vector{1 ,2 , 3 , 4 , 5}, 6);
    std::cout << y[5] << '\n'; // 6
    return 0;
}
```

And finally, one can do this if you want to use old-style c functions:

```
template <typename R, typename ...Args>
inline auto CFunc(R (*iFunc) (Args...)) {
    return Function<R (*) (Args...)>(iFunc);
}
```

Is this robust code? Are there edge cases I need to be aware about with which my functor class does not work? Also, how could I provide more suitable error messages, eg when `typename Functor` is not a functor, or when `args...` are not suitable parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming C++20, we can constrain the template (similar to your attempt at `static_assert`).  The key is that `Args...` can contain rvalue-references, but we need to convert those to lvalue types, because that's what we present to the function:

```
#include <concepts>
```

```
    template<typename... Args>
    inline auto operator()(Args&&... args)
        requires std::invocable<Functor, std::add_lvalue_reference_t<Args>...>
```

I don't see anything else I would propose improving.